# Understanding definition and desugaring of "Option" in Scala 3 book

Tags: scala, scala-3

I'm starting a Scala role in a few weeks yet I haven't written any Scala before (yes, my future employers know this), although I've written a lot of C# and Haskell. Anyway I was skimming through the Scala 3 book, and found this [example](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/types-adts-gadts.html):

```
enum Option[+T]:
  case Some(x: T)
  case None
```

Which apparently dusugars into:

```
enum Option[+T]:
  case Some(x: T) extends Option[T]
  case None       extends Option[Nothing]
```

My two questions are:

1. How exactly does the mechanism of this desugaring work? In particular why does `Some` by  default extend `Option[T]` whereas `None` extends `Option[Nothing]`?
2. This seems like a strange way to define `Option`. I would define it like this:

```
enum Option[+T]:
  case Some(x: T) extends Option[T]
  case None       extends Option[T]
```

Indeed with `None` extending `Option[None]` wouldn't this fail?

```
Option[string] x = None;
```

As `Option[T]` is covariant in `T` and `None` is not a subtype of `string`?

I'm missing something quite fundamental here I'm sure.

Comment: Is your new job going to be Scala 3 or Scala 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An excellent source for how desugaring of enums works is the original proposal at [Issue #1970](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/1970).

The relevant section for your question on that page is titled "Desugarings". Let's take a look at your `Option` definition.

```
enum Option[+T]:
  case Some(x: T)
  case None
```

`Some` is a parameterized case under an enum with type parameters, so Rule #4 applies

> If E is an enum class with type parameters Ts, then a case in its companion object without an extends clause
>
> ```
> case C <params> <body>
> ```
>
> ...
>
> For the case where C does not have type parameters, assume E's type parameters are
>
> ```
> V1 T1 > L1 <: U1 ,   ... ,    Vn Tn >: Ln <: Un      (n > 0)
> ```
>
> where each of the variances Vi is either '+' or '-'. Then the case expands to
>
> ```
> case C <params> extends E[B1, ..., Bn] <body>
> ```

So your `Some` case gets an `extends` clause for `Option[T]`, as you'd expect. Then Rule #5 gets us our actual case class.

On the other hand, your `None`, by the same token, uses *no* type parameters, so the result is based on variance.

- If `T` is invariant, we *have* to specify an `extends` clause explicitly
- If `T` is covariant, we get `Nothing`
- If `T` is contravariant, we get `Any`

Your `T` is covariant, so we extend `Option[Nothing]`, which remember is a subtype of `Option[S]` for *any* `S`. Hence, your assignment (and remember, in Scala, we use `val` / `var` to declare variables, not just the type name)

```
val x: Option[String] = None;
```

`None` is a value of type `None.type`, which extends `Option[Nothing]`. `Option[Nothing]` is a subtype of `Option[String]` since `Nothing` is a subtype of `String`. So the assignment succeeds.

This is the same reason `Nil` (the empty list) extends `List[Nothing]`. I can construct a `Nil` which has a concrete type (a subtype of `List[Nothing]`), and then later I can come along and prepend whatever I want to it. The resulting list is no longer a `List[Nothing]`; `1 +: Nil` is a `List[Int]` and `"a" +: Nil` is a `List[String]`, but the point is, that `Nil` can come from anywhere in my program and we don't have to decide what type we want it to be up-front. We can't (safely) use covariance on a mutable data type, so this all only works because `List` and `Option` are immutable. A mutable collection like `ArrayBuffer` is invariant in its type parameter. (Note: Java's built-in arrays are covariant, and that's [unsound](http://wiki.c2.com/?JavaArraysBreakTypeSafety) and causes all kinds of problems)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! All makes sense now, And also how lists work!

Answer (score 2):

1. the desugaring is part of a compiler phase, the more important ou need to understand is that enum in scala3 replaces coproduct/sum types of scala 2.
   it is a tagged union type essentially.
2. Nothing is a bottom type, so it extends from everything. It is the dual of Any(root object)

ps: I can expand on those if you want, let me know

Answer (score 2):

> How exactly does the mechanism of this desugaring work? In particular
> why does Some by default extend Option[T] whereas None extends
> Option[Nothing]?

`Some` by default extends `Option[T]` as it has a type parameter as an argument `(x: T)` and is treated similarly (but not exactly the same) as a case class, while `None` is treated as a "regular" Enum value as it does not have a parameter list definition.

We can further analyze the typer compilation phase by adding `-Xprint:typer`:

```
sealed abstract class MyOption[T >: Nothing <: Any]()
     extends
   Object(), scala.reflect.Enum {
    +T
    import MyOption.{MySome, None}
  }

final lazy module val MyOption: MyOption$ = new MyOption$()
final module class MyOption$() extends AnyRef() { this: MyOption.type =>
final case class MySome[T](x: T) extends MyOption[MySome.this.T]() {
  +T
  val x: T
  def copy[T](x: T): MyOption.MySome[T] = new MyOption.MySome[T](x)
  def copy$default$1[T]: T = MySome.this.x
  def ordinal: Int = 0
  def _1: T = this.x
}
final lazy module val MySome: MyOption.MySome$ = new MyOption.MySome$()
final module class MySome$() extends AnyRef() { 
  this: MyOption.MySome.type =>
  def apply[T](x: T): MyOption.MySome[T] = new MyOption.MySome[T](x)
  def unapply[T](x$1: MyOption.MySome[T]): MyOption.MySome[T] = x$1
  override def toString: String = "MySome"
}
case <static> val None: MyOption[Nothing] = 
  {
    final class $anon() extends MyOption[Nothing](), scala.runtime.EnumValue {
      def ordinal: Int = 1
    }
    new $anon(): MyOption[Nothing] & runtime.EnumValue
  }
```

We can see `MySome` is expanded into a `case class`, while `None` is expanded into a value defined on `MyOption`.

[Silvio provided the "specification"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67887206/1870803) for `enum` definitions (as of today (08/06/2021) I can't find a formal one), where rules 4 and 7 are what we're looking for:

> If E is an enum class with type parameters Ts, then a case in its companion object without an extends clause
>
> ```
> case C <params> <body>
> ```
>
> ...
>
> For the case where C does not have type parameters, assume E's type parameters are
>
> ```
> V1 T1 > L1 <: U1 ,   ... ,    Vn Tn >: Ln <: Un      (n > 0)
> ```
>
> where each of the variances Vi is either '+' or '-'. Then the case expands to
>
> ```
> case C <params> extends E[B1, ..., Bn] <body>
> ```

And for the `None` case:

> case C of an enum class E that does not take type parameters expands
> to
>
> ```
> val C = $new(n, "C")
> ```
>
> Here, $new is a private method that creates an
> instance of of E (see below).

---

> This seems like a strange way to define Option.

Not really, it makes sense when you think about it. `None` is treated a singleton in this case, and since `T` is covariant in it's argument type, and [`Nothing` is a bottom type which means it inherits all other types in Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html#nothing-and-null), it works for any assignment.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I was thinking `Nothing` was like `Any` but it's actually at the opposite end.

As a sidenote, is there anyway to define types like `Nothing` in Scalacode or is it only a magical compiler generated thing?

Comment: You can definitely define it, but it is an uninhabited type.

Comment: How would I define `MyNothing` without using `Nothing`?

Comment: You can use it in a type definition, but you cannot inhabit it with a value.

Comment: @Clinton you can not really define your own `Nothing` because the fact that it is the subtype of all types is compiler magic.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez just checking